# taking form input value into a new created div "note"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a school project, where they asked us to create a form where you input values, and when you click submit, a new note will shoe and will be filled with the values from the form.
My problem is that I can't understand how to write the function that creates the notes with the values from the form.

I already did the form and the design for the page. Also started the function to create the note.

This is the form:

```
<form id="form1">
Mission Details: <textarea name="Details" rows="3" cols="20"></textarea> <br> <br>
Mission Due Date: <input type="Date" name="Date"> <br> <br>
Mission Due Time: <input type="Text" name="Time"> <br> <br>
<button type="button" onsubmit="createNote()"> Submit </button> 
<button type="button" onclick="Clear()"> Clear </button>
</form>
```

This is the script i started:

```
function CreateNote(event) {
var form = event.currentTarget; 
var details = form.Details.value;
var date = form.Date.value;
var time = form.Time.value;
}
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
form.onsubmit = CreateNote();
```

This is the div for the note and note content:

```
<div class="note">
    <div class="noteDetails"> 

    </div>
</div>
```

Eventually, the note will have a background from an image in a CSS file, and inside that note, it will have the values from the form.

Comment: There is nothing in here that displays anything.

Comment: grammar changes

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Create a template for your note, lets say you display your text with `<p></p>`.

**2.** Leave it with empty values. Give it an id, lets call it `"details"`.

**3.** After you have the desired values, use `document.getElementById("details")`, and fill the `<p>` with the value.

```
<div class="note">
    <div class="noteDetails"> 
        <p id="details"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

then in your JavaScript you can use

```
var stringInput = "Some String";
var detailsElement = document.getElementById("details");
detailsElement.innerHTML = " stringInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now use your div `noteDetails`. Inside it create three `p` elements with id `details`, `date` and `time`.

eg:

```
<div class="noteDetails">
  <p id="details"></p>
  <p id="date"></p>
  <p id="time"></p>
</div>
```

Change your button element to:

```
<button type="button" onclick="createNote()"> Submit </button>
```

**Note:** your using `createNote()` in html and using `CreateNote` in JS

and inside your `createNote` function just add

```
function createNote() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form1'); 
  var details = form.Details.value;
  var date = form.Date.value;
  var time = form.Time.value;

  var detailsPara = document.querySelector('#details');
  detailsPara.innerText = details;

  var datePara = document.querySelector('#date');
  datePara.innerText = date;

  var timePara = document.querySelector('#time');
  timePara.innerText = time;
}
```

remove lines from your code

```
var form = document.getElementById('form1');
form.onsubmit = CreateNote();
```

**UPDATE:** if input values are to be shown immediately then add these to html

```
Mission Details: <textarea name="Details" rows="3" cols="20" oninput="createNote()"></textarea> <br> <br>
Mission Due Date: <input type="Date" name="Date" oninput="createNote()"> <br> <br>
Mission Due Time: <input type="Text" name="Time" oninput="createNote()"> <br> <br>
```

Comment: Thank you, helped me! The thing is that i need that the new div created should have the form input values written on it. How can i make that happen?

Comment: if you are saying that form input values are to be shown immediately after we type them then you can use "oninput" event  handler. i will update the answer